# Problems using ssh and socket from C# since Skype installation

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssh

I am using on different projects SSH (Granados library) and socket (socket.net). It was working pretty well on all my C# projects, but now I have installed Skype, and it is not working anymore.

I tried on another computer and it appeared to be exactly the same: working before installing Skype, but not working after.

Even if I uninstall Skype (already tried), it's not working anymore.

Does anyone has an idea of where my problem come from? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by ”not working”? Is it fails to bind to a port, during a connection establishing or what?

Comment: Is there an error message that is displayed?

Comment: System.Exception: Socket Problem. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n'a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d'une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l'hôte de connexion n'a pas répondu 192.168.4.142:35035
   à System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   à System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)

Comment: Any chance of getting that in english?

Comment: Sorry for that... ^^' Here is the translation ! System.Exception: Socket Problem. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : A try to connect failed because the connected part not answered after a define duration or the connexion faild because the host never answered 192.168.4.142:35035 to System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) à System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP) 

Sorry for that again... ANd thanks for the help !

Comment: @Joe Did you solve it? Please accept the correct answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your firewall settings got messed up by the Skype installation.
Check if the allowed port settings are still as they should be.

Or there may be a conflict of Skype with the ports you are using with your C# apps.
Using other port numbers should solve it.